# How do I accumulate data until it is ready to be sent over serial?

Tags: c++, serial-port, arduino

I'm trying to create a fast protocol for communicating with the Arduino via serial. My primary purpose for this is learning new code methods, so this may not be optimal.

I'm planning to create a "virtual Arduino" in memory, which has arrays for the pin states and other info. Instead of sending every single pin change as separate commands, I would make changes to this "vitual Arduino", which would then accumulate only the changes and send those.

So for instance, if I was updating the Arduino really slowly, like every 0.1 seconds, and I had made 100 changes during that time, I would like to accumulate those changes in between there and send them all at once.

In my case, I'm wanting to make a buffer. That way if 20 changes occur while waiting for serial to finish sending the previous command, it can accumulate those changes and send them all at once when serial is available again.

I already have a method of how to actually ACCUMULATE the changes: changes will be made to an array representing the pins.

However, I need a subroutine that sends these changes as soon as serial is available again. It can't happen in normal sequential programming, because I don't want it to wait until I'm done calculating something to go ahead and send the changes. I'm thinking of something like an interrupt or a separate thread.

So if I did something like this:

```
while(1)
{
   if( SerialAvailable() )
        Send(changes);
   else
       -DO STUFF HERE-
}
```

problem would be that it wouldn't send updates until AFTER it was done with everything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In many embedded systems, there are two methods for using the serial port:  polling and interrupt.  In polling, your program checks a status bit.  In interrupt, the port generates and interrupt and the interrupt service routine (ISR) takes over.

Looks like you want your serial port configured to interrupt when the transmit register is empty.  The transmit interrupt service routine could take accumulated data and send through the port when the transmit register is empty.  The ISR could also set a semaphore that indicates the serial port is available.

In my embedded system, the port uses FIFO memory.  The interrupt is triggered when the FIFO is empty.  The ISR reloads the FIFO from a circular queue.  If the queue is empty, a semaphore (flag) is set so that the printing function can reload the circular queue.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds a lot like what I'm looking for. Though it sounds like you're doing it on the embedded end, which is useful to me, but I'm mostly looking for how to do this on the PC end in C++.